# fopen: $JOHN/dynamic.conf: No such file or directory

Tags: security

I have an unshadowed db.txt file:

```
[root@SERVER ~]# rpm -qa | grep -i john
john-1.7.9-1.el6.rf.x86_64
[root@SERVER ~]# head -1 /etc/issue
Scientific Linux release 6.3 (Carbon)
[root@SERVER ~]# cat db.txt 
cecil:$6$iHc0bEXn$IxtX8x0TCx6h13qTH8yVjf5cGwT25AitFEQpJc3cP6qgN4LLMiJfDD2pQGUyZFX7JYeGneX34j38tNZHAgQsV/:503:504::/home/cecil:/bin/bash
[root@SERVER ~]# john db.txt 
fopen: $JOHN/dynamic.conf: No such file or directory
[root@SERVER ~]# ls -la .john/
összesen 44
drwx------.  2 root root  4096 máj   31 11.27 .
dr-xr-x---. 15 root root  4096 máj   31 11.35 ..
-rw-------.  1 root root     0 máj   31 11.24 dynamic.conf
-rw-------.  1 root root 36305 máj   31 11.27 john.conf
-rw-------.  1 root root     0 máj   31 11.24 john.ini
[root@SERVER ~]#
```

But can't resolve the:

```
fopen: $JOHN/dynamic.conf: No such file or directory
```

error message. How can I? I already touched john.ini & dynamic.conf & copied john.conf from /etc..

UPDATE:

```
[root@SERVER ~]# john db.txt 
fopen: $JOHN/dynamic.conf: No such file or directory
[root@SERVER ~]# echo $JOHN

[root@SERVER ~]#
```

The $JOHN variable is empty.

UPDATE2: I updated to SL 6.4, but still the same, after a reboot too.

Comment: What is the value of `$JOHN`? Please include the output of `echo $JOHN`.

Comment: How about `export JOHN=~/.john`?

Comment: `strace -f -e trace=file john db.txt` should tell you precisely what the problem is.

Comment: Try `JOHN=. john db.txt` or maybe `JOHN=$PWD`?

Comment: Use `locate dynamic.conf` to see where it should be looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

comment the next line in `/etc/john.conf`

```
.include dynamic.conf
```